SharePoint and Clarity analytics, specifically numbers of page viewers
I have just recently integrated Clarity with SharePoint online.
for some sites, i get a reasonable match in hits, using out of the box analytics - there may be a slight discrepancy, but that's fine.
however for some site collections, clarity is reporting for example 21 hits, whereas for a similar time period, SharePoint analytics is reporting over 5,000.
i have tried filters, but no luck.
Anyone know for the reason in such a massive difference?
many thanks
i have tried comparing several popular sites that are identified using Clarity then compared to SharePoint analytics numbers

Whether you use SharePoint online or SharePoint server? Which way you use to check page view?
